# How do I find a list of indexes on a temporary table that I've created in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporary, database-indexes

Please can some one help me to get a list of indexes on a temporary table that I've created in SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, INDEXCOLUMN BIGINT)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_TMPINDEX' AND OBJECT_ID = object_id('tempdb..#tmpTable'))
BEGIN
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TMPINDEX ON #tmpTable (INDEXCOLUMN)    
END

GO 

SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes WHERE OBJECT_ID = object_id('tempdb..#tmpTable')
```

Comment: Why can't you use something like SELECT object_id('tempdb..IX_TMPINDEX'); Or can you?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, using [`sp_helpindex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188771.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int, val1 int)

CREATE INDEX ix_t1 on #temp (id)

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_helpindex '#temp'
```